# Cannot connect with Docker container from inside a swarm and the host machine

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm composing two containers, one with the web services and one with the database.
Here's my compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
    container_name: web
    ports:
    - 5555:80
    links:
    - db
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:rc1
    container_name: db
    ports:
    - 1533:1433
    environment:
    - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
    - "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyAdminPwd2017"
    - "MSSQL_PID=Developer"
```

So, from my asp.net core app running in the `web` service I can access the database at `db` just using `db` as hostname. But `db` is not visible from the host (I have a default bridge network). I do can access my database from the host if I inspect the running db container and find it's ip address, then I can connect to `<ip>,1533`.

The thing is, the file storing the the credentials to access the database is used both by the `web` container and the host machine. So I need a way to name  `db` so I can access from both worlds (being inside the swarm and outside, from my host machine)

Is there a way to achieve that? I tried defining a host network in my `docker-compose` file and have both services uses that network, but I got a message saying only I one host network can be defined.

EDIT: tried to improve the question title but I'm still not convinced, improvements are welcome

Comment: From your host machine, you can access db using "localhost:<exposed port>". You can create an alias in your host machine from "localhost:<exposed port>" to "db". Would that help you? By having host network, you dont get benefits of container network isolation.

Comment: Thanks, by creating an alias in my host machine (Windows) you mean creating an entry in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, right?  I'd really prefer no to do that. What if I don't care about the container network isolation and I want both containers and my host to be in the same network? can I achieve that?

Comment: Inside Docker, dns resolution happens in Docker engine for containers and uses external dns server for names that are not resolved. The host has no idea about Docker engine's DNS database. In your case, you want the container and host to have the same DNS database for db. Simplest way is to host alias, that seems not usable for you. 1 way i can think of is to use external dns server like consul and publish the services from your containers to the external server and have both containers and host use that dns server.

Comment: Thanks what about IP address?. When I fire Windows Containers each of them has an IP address I can connect either from another container as from the host itself. Can I achieve that with Linux (regular) containers?

Comment: Container ip address in bridge network is accessible from host. For overlay network, container ip address is not accessible from host. This behavior is same for Linux and Windows containers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, to answer my own question, what I want is not posible, at least as of today.

Somebody wrote a nice article on why I can't achieve what I want. Having said that, it is doable in Windows Containers, but it might be a temporary "limitation".

Link to the post: https://derickbailey.com/2016/08/29/so-youre-saying-docker-isnt-a-virtual-machine/
and link to the Docker Forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/access-dockerized-services-via-the-containers-ip-address/21151